# SpringBoot+REST+Security - either all access open or all closed

Tags: spring, rest, security, spring-boot, configuration

What I am trying to do should be pretty easy: 
a REST-Service with 3 different security levels:

- A "public" RestService accessible by all
- A "protected" RestService for "USER"s
- A "private" RestService for "ADMIN"s

but either I have Access to all - or with the current config I got acces to NONE, because Without BasicAuth I always got

- Full authentication is required to access this resource

and with the "uuu" + "ppp" I always got

- Bad credentials

By the way I using spring boot 1.5.3

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("aaa").password("ppp").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("uuu").password("ppp").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // We don't need sessions to be created.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web 
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    }
}
```

Comment: `auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("aaa").password("ppp").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and().withUser("uuu").password("ppp").roles("USER")`

Answer (score 0):

The OP found their solution actually works. There was a problem with the component-Scan, because my Rest project is a child of my DAO and Repository-Project...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.leycarno.base", "com.leycarno.rest"}) // now we're listen to all the nice components :-)
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.leycarno.base.repositories")
@EntityScan("com.leycarno.base.models")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```